# Tensorflow: what are "input_mean" and "input_std" in label_image.py in tensorflow example

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

I am using Windows 7.
I have train a mobilenet using the official retraining example.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining

I have run command like this:

```
python ../tensorflow-master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py --image_dir test/ --learning_rate=0.0001 --testing_percentage=20 --validation_percentage=20 --train_batch_size=32 --validation_batch_size=-1 --flip_left_right True --random_scale=30 --random_brightness=30 --eval_step_interval=100 --how_many_training_steps=2000 --architecture mobilenet_0.25_128
```

And I get the trained graph and label files "output_graph.pb" and "output_labels.txt".

Now, I want to perform classification using the above generated graph, so I used the label_image.py provided in tensorflow github.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import sys

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def load_graph(model_file):
  graph = tf.Graph()
  graph_def = tf.GraphDef()

  with open(model_file, "rb") as f:
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
  with graph.as_default():
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

  return graph

def read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name, input_height=299, input_width=299,
                input_mean=0, input_std=255):
  input_name = "file_reader"
  output_name = "normalized"
  file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
  if file_name.endswith(".png"):
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_png(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                       name='png_reader')
  elif file_name.endswith(".gif"):
    image_reader = tf.squeeze(tf.image.decode_gif(file_reader,
                                                  name='gif_reader'))
  elif file_name.endswith(".bmp"):
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_bmp(file_reader, name='bmp_reader')
  else:
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                        name='jpeg_reader')
  float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
  dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0);
  resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height, input_width])
  normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])
  sess = tf.Session()
  result = sess.run(normalized)

  return result

def load_labels(label_file):
  label = []
  proto_as_ascii_lines = tf.gfile.GFile(label_file).readlines()
  for l in proto_as_ascii_lines:
    label.append(l.rstrip())
  return label

if __name__ == "__main__":
  file_name = "tensorflow/examples/label_image/data/grace_hopper.jpg"
  model_file = \
    "tensorflow/examples/label_image/data/inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb"
  label_file = "tensorflow/examples/label_image/data/imagenet_slim_labels.txt"
  input_height = 299
  input_width = 299
  input_mean = 0
  input_std = 255
  input_layer = "input"
  output_layer = "InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1"

  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--image", help="image to be processed")
  parser.add_argument("--graph", help="graph/model to be executed")
  parser.add_argument("--labels", help="name of file containing labels")
  parser.add_argument("--input_height", type=int, help="input height")
  parser.add_argument("--input_width", type=int, help="input width")
  parser.add_argument("--input_mean", type=int, help="input mean")
  parser.add_argument("--input_std", type=int, help="input std")
  parser.add_argument("--input_layer", help="name of input layer")
  parser.add_argument("--output_layer", help="name of output layer")
  args = parser.parse_args()

  if args.graph:
    model_file = args.graph
  if args.image:
    file_name = args.image
  if args.labels:
    label_file = args.labels
  if args.input_height:
    input_height = args.input_height
  if args.input_width:
    input_width = args.input_width
  if args.input_mean:
    input_mean = args.input_mean
  if args.input_std:
    input_std = args.input_std
  if args.input_layer:
    input_layer = args.input_layer
  if args.output_layer:
    output_layer = args.output_layer

  graph = load_graph(model_file)
  t = read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,
                                  input_height=input_height,
                                  input_width=input_width,
                                  input_mean=input_mean,
                                  input_std=input_std)

  input_name = "import/" + input_layer
  output_name = "import/" + output_layer
  input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
  output_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(output_name);

  with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                      {input_operation.outputs[0]: t})
  results = np.squeeze(results)

  top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
  labels = load_labels(label_file)
  for i in top_k:
    print(labels[i], results[i])
```

And I run the following command:

```
python ../tensorflow-master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py --graph=output_graph.pb --labels=output_labels.txt --image=test.jpg --input_layer=input --output_layer=final_result --input_mean=128 --input_std=128 --input_width=128 --input_height=128
```

And the image "test.jpg" can be classified.

However, when I use different values for "input_mean" and "input_std", the result changes.

What are "input_mean" and "input_std" used for? And how can I get correct values for these 2 parameters?

Comment: Please, provide the code you're using.

Comment: @Lescurel I have added related link containing the .py files I have used

Comment: You should embed the code in your question, as the link could change in the future.

Comment: @Lescure I have added code of label_image.py, but I do not copy the code of retrain.py as there is a word limitation

Comment: They are parameters selected by the `--architecture` parameter in the training. It looks like they should be both `127.5`, but I don't have any explanation why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two variables, are used to normalize the dataset, as we observe improvement in the result of doing so.
The `input_mean`, is the mean per channel of the dataset, and the `input_std` is the standard deviation associated. As you control which dataset you pass in your Network, you should be able to calculate the mean and the std.

Normalization means 2 things:

- Putting the data on the same scale (Scaling)
- Balancing the data around a point (Centering (around 0 in our case))

As to why we do that, you could read about it in this Crossvalidated answer : https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/220970

> "Subtracting the dataset mean serves to "center" the data.
>   Additionally, you ideally would like to divide by the sttdev of that
>   feature or pixel as well if you want to normalize each feature value
>   to a z-score.
>
> The reason we do both of those things is because in the process of
>   training our network, we're going to be multiplying (weights) and
>   adding to (biases) these initial inputs in order to cause activations
>   that we then backpropogate with the gradients to train the model.
>
> We'd like in this process for each feature to have a similar range so
>   that our gradients don't go out of control (and that we only need one
>   global learning rate multiplier). "

EDIT : giving an example
Imagine your image is a really simple image of 3 pixels :

```
img = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]]
```

You can easily compute the mean per channel

```
mean = [4,5,6]
```

And as easily the std per channel too:

```
std = [2.45,2.45,2.45]
```

As tensorflow will do an element-wise subtraction, and then an element-wise division, you will normalize individually each channel of your image.

In the code, it seems that they add a dimensions to be compliant with the tf.image functions. As the first dimension is the batch one, you should prepend your arrays with a 0. (`[0,4,5,6]`)

Comment: That means I have to calculate mean and std of image color of all channel in this CASE?

Comment: The mean per channel option will give you best results. Instead of an int, pass an array of mean and std. I will update my answer to provide an example.